# the enter key does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

the enter key does not work. After filling out the form does not work.I do not want to use the form tag.

```
<div>
    <label style="color:white;"> Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="span2" name="loginname" id="loginname"  />
    <label style="color:white;"> password</label>
    <input type="password" class="span2" name="loginpass" id="loginpass" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" autofocus onclick="login()">enter</button> 

</div>
```

because i used ajax with codeginiter.

```
  function login(){
          var usr = $('#loginname').val();
          var pass= $('#loginpass').val();
         $.ajax({ 
                      type: "POST", 
                      url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/user/register",
                       data: {          "isim": usr,
                                        'pass' : sifre,
                                      },
                      success: function(msg){
                        if (msg=="ok") {
                         window.location = "http://localhost/ci/index.php/user/main";

                         }else{

                              new Messi(msg, {title: 'ERROR', modal: true});
                         }
                      }
                    });
     }
        }
```

}

Comment: add your js function login() in question.

Comment: try `onsubmit` instead on `onclick`

Comment: Why would you not use tags that are specifically designed for your purpose?

Comment: Without a form tag you can't submit a form with Enter key. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean you do not want to use the `form` tag? How else will your values be submitted?

Comment: i used ajax and with codeigniter.

Comment: @osmansert have u got ur answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want use `form tag` you can use `ajax`
try this:
this is javascript/jquery for your `login()` function that you use in `onclick`

```
function login(){
    loginName = $('#loginname').val();
    loginPass = $('#loginpass').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourActionUrl?cmd=login&amp;loginname=' + loginname + '&amp;loginpass=' + loginPass,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

see [ajax website](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information

Comment: thanks. but enter button dont work.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
  Pwd: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS file**

```
function divClicked() {
$(this).html("Clicked");
//Do form submission
}

$(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").addClass("hidden");
    $("form").append($(document.createElement("div")).html("My div").click(divClicked));
});
```

**css file**

```
input.hidden {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the JSFIDDLE  http://jsfiddle.net/Suyw6/1/

Comment: i am editing question.i dont form because  i use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use enter you need to have a form and on form add event onSubmit. then it will work for both submit button and enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed "enter" somewhere');
            //you login call goes here
    }
});
```

You can also change that to grab keypresses from either textboxes